# How to edit blog titles in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'd like to edit the titles of the blog posts but can't see how to do this on Word Press. I've managed to make them bold but that's as far as I could get. I'd like to change the size and font and perhaps centre them.

This is the blog: http://www.movimientos.org.uk/blog/

(Also, if there's anything else you could suggest which you think would make the blog look a little nicer then any advice would be much appreciated!)

Thanks,
Helen

Comment: Why don't you modify the `style.css` of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

This essentially comes down to the theme that you use. And on which pages you want to make the edit. The best advice i can give you is go into your themes main folder and look at "single.php".

What you're looking for is a line that says:

```
<?php the_title ?>
```

It should be there along with  around the same area. You should be able to style it yourself from there by seeing what classes are being used in that section.

Answer (score 0):

There are many themes with a GUI to edit the entire header (logo,title, font, and more options), usually the "responsive" themes have this option.
Look for a new theme under "Appearance" section.

If you want to edit something specific you can also use the CSS editor too under appearance.